# External HDD ESXi VM Snapshot backups

Tags: vmware-esxi, nfs, ghettovcb

I have a couple of ESXi hosts running a few servers on each and would like to backup to my external drive plugged into one of my hosts.

I have setup ghettoVCB scripts on each host with a list of my vm's to be backed up and have this automated using cronjobs.

How do I set the external up as the NFS, would this have to be done through one of my existing Windows VM's?

Edit: I have just found out that you can't mount an external drive as a datastore in ESXi 5.x
However this is specifically where my client would like their backups stored, from both hosts and preferably automatically

---

Yes that is correct, I am using the ESXi eval version for testing. Unfortunately due to this I'm having to do this the difficult way instead of using something like Veeam, which will only work on licensed ESX installations.

I was going to use Hyper V to begin with but agreed on ESXi and have setup quite a bit so don't want to start from scratch preferably.

I am going to try to mount the external in FreeNAS and make it a network share so my ghettoVCB can point to it.

Any other suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Yeah, there's no nice solution for this. A USB disk won't work.

Comment: I am guessing you are running the free version, maybe switch to hyper-v?  It is a decent hypervisor which supports all hardware that Windows Server supports?

Answer (score 0):

[Veeam](https://www.veeam.com) is a commercial solution that *can* work. Licensed vSphere is relatively cheap. It would be less than $500US to accomplish that for up to 6 CPU sockets. I'm assuming that it's possible to get approval for such a purchase.